# JavaFX custom component usage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have a problem with my custom component in JavaFX.

My custom component contains split pane that contains TableView and TabPane:

**MasterDetail.fxml**

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane>
                    <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="table"/>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>

                <AnchorPane>
                    <children>
                        <TabPane fx:id="tabPane"/>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

I want to use my custom control in another fxml so I created it and how I can declare columns for TableView in my MasterDetail component?

For example I want to do something like this:

```
<MasterDetail fx:id="masterDetail">
    <table>
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="createDateColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Create date"/>
        </columns>
    </table>
</MasterDetail>
```

It is ever possible to do this in fxml?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define the number of table columns in the 'masterDetail' component. But to happen we have to define custom properties which reads the table columns.

Example :

```
   <CustomeTable>
        <children>
          <TableView fx:id="table"/>
        </children>
  </CustomeTable>
```

Define CustomeTable which extends AnchorPane.

```
public class CustomeTable extends AnchorPane{

    private ObjectProperty<Integer> noOfColumns = new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>();

public void setNoOfColumns(Integer noOfColumns){
noOfColumns.set(noOfColumns);    
}

public Integer getNoOfColumns(){
return noOfColumns.get();
}

public CustomeTable(){

// add the listener to the ObjectProperty
// which updates the noOfColumns into table
noOfCoulmns.addListener();

}


}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to create a custom component (MasterDetial.fxml) that contains a table. And later I want to use this component in fxml and I want define column for the table that is definied in MasterDetail.fxml.

For example in MasterDetail.fxml, I have empty table without any columns and later I want to create another fxml which use component and add column to table which I defined in MasterDetail.